# Find final degree in motor motion

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume, we have a motor whose velocity is variable. This motor starts from 0 degree position with 0 degree/Second to 120 degree/Second velocity in 5 second. I want to know how many degrees does this motor move in 5 second?
Here is the diagram of velocity and time of motion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z47FE.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the position $\theta$. Then you have the angular velocity $\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, and the angular acceleration $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$. From your graph, you have a constant angular acceleration $$\alpha=\frac{120^\circ/s}{5s}=24^\circ/s^2$$
The angular velocity as a function of time can be obtained from:$$d\omega=\alpha dt$$by integrating between $t=0$ and some time $t$. $$\int_{\omega(t=0)}^{\omega(t)} d\omega=\int_0^t\alpha dt$$
This yields $$\omega(t)-\omega(0)=\alpha(t-0)$$
You have the condition taht at $t=0$ the angular velocity is zero, so $$\omega(t)=\alpha t$$
We repeat now the same reasoning to find the angle as a function of time:
$$d\theta=\omega(t)\ dt\\\int_{\theta(t=0)}^{\theta(t)}d\theta=\int_0^t\omega(t)\ dt\\\theta(t)-\theta(t=0)=\int_{t=0}^t\alpha \ t \ dt$$
You have $\theta(t=0)=0$, so $$\theta(t)=\frac{\alpha}2t^2$$

Comment: I really appreciate your swift and complete response. In reality, I set the first speed to .855 d/s instead of zero, first position to 0 degree, and final speed=120 d/s. However by observing the output movement, I saw 344 degree after 5 seconds. I solved your question for these values and I got 304.27. Does it correct or I did some mistakes.

Comment: In general, for any given initial condition, if the acceleration is constant you get $$\theta(t)=\theta(t=0)+\omega(t=0)t+\frac{\alpha}2 t^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable help.